# Use ssh into machine and get back load info

Tags: ssh

I have ssh access to a list of ~20 machines. I need to find the load status for all of them in a list. The program 'top' does a good job giving info on the machine status in its header.

Example:

```
top - 13:29:53 up 107 days, 20:13, 47 users,  load average: 3.80, 3.74, 3.62
Tasks: 794 total,   2 running, 787 sleeping,   3 stopped,   2 zombie
Cpu(s):  2.6%us,  0.8%sy,  0.0%ni, 84.7%id, 11.9%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  99055876k total, 47947572k used, 51108304k free,   697684k buffers
Swap: 26148860k total, 17145136k used,  9003724k free, 35844820k cached
```

Today I manually do ssh into each machine, do the 'top' copy the data and store it. I was wondering if this task can be automated. I found out that ssh has the option of giving a unix cmd as an argument to be executed on the remote machine. But how to capture the output from 'top'? Or is there a batch-too giving the same header output? It would be great to have just one script that does the table for me.

Thanks,
Gert

Comment: This sounds like a great case for using Ansible and the fetch module. This could all be automated into a playbook that way and copied to your local machine. [https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/fetch_module.html#fetch](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/fetch_module.html#fetch)

Comment: Much of the information that top returns is even fetched automatically at the start of an Ansible (or Chef, or Puppet) run. Just getting the `uptime` of a set of machines is just a list of servers iin the inventory.ini file and then `ansible all --inventory=inventory.ini  -m command -a 'uptime'`

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu:

```
[12:15 AM] borlaze@mac: /tmp $ ssh USER@HOST 'top -b -n 1 | head -n 5' >123.txt

[12:15 AM] borlaze@mac: /tmp $ cat 123.txt
top - 00:16:06 up 35 days, 10:58,  1 user,  load average: 0,34, 0,36, 0,29
Tasks: 277 total,   1 running, 274 sleeping,   0 stopped,   2 zombie
%Cpu(s):  7,1 us,  5,7 sy,  0,0 ni, 87,0 id,  0,1 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem : 24671340 total,  1066056 free, 12822724 used, 10782560 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 16756732 total, 16094308 free,   662424 used. 11208916 avail Mem
```